# System.out.println();

Tags: java

Что делает пустой метод `System.out.println()`? не  совсем понимаю, для чего выводят пустой метод. Данный код выводит таблицу Пифагора, ниже задача:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
           for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
             for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                 System.out.print(i * j);
                System.out.print(" ");
             }
             System.out.println();
         }
  
     }
```

Comment: Почитайте про `print()` и `println()` в документации, и сразу станет понятно, в чём разница и зачем.

Comment: А убрать и посмотреть на разницу - не?

Answer (score 2):

println() — вывод переданной информации и перевод строки. В качестве аргументов может принимать числа, строки, другие объекты;

В вашем случае аргумент - пустая строка. Таким образом происходит вывод пустой строки (т.е. не выводится ничего), после чего происходит перевод на следующую строку.

Answer (score 1):

- print -   выводит символы на текущей строке.
- println - переводит курсор на следующую строку.